# How do I use Weld and EclipseLink together in an SE environment?

Tags: unit-testing, jpa, weld

I am trying to create a unit test that uses EclipseLink via JPA and I noticed that I needed to inject a DAO into a listener.  The code itself works as expected inside a container, but I am having trouble making a unit test for it.

The listener looks like this.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ParticipantListener {

    @Inject
    private ParticipantDAO dao;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    void ensureNoDuplicateSin(final Participant e) throws DuplicateSinException {

        final Participant bySin = dao.getBySinAndNotSelf(e.getSin(), e);
        if (bySin != null && bySin.getId() != e.getId()) {
            throw new DuplicateSinException();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run in a unit test `dao` is not injected.

My test is initialized as follows:

```
    weld = new Weld();
    final WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
    vf = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    final Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put("javax.persistence.provider", "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider");
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test-pu", props);
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

which obviously should not work because there's no relationship between the `em/emf` and the `container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the `javax.persistence.bean.manager` to point to Weld's bean manager.  In addition I found that I also

```
    weld = new Weld();
    final WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
    final JpaProvider jpaProvider = container.select(JpaProvider.class).get();

    final Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put("javax.persistence.provider", "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider");
    props.put("javax.persistence.bean.manager", container.getBeanManager());
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test-pu", props);
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    jpaProvider.setEntityManager(em);
```

In addition I had to change the DAO to not use `@PersistenceContext` and use `@Inject` for the entity manager and create a JpaProvider class.  During the test it will set the entity manager from the container instance.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class JpaProvider {

    private EntityManager em;

    @Produces
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {

        return em;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(final EntityManager em) {

        this.em = em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution sounds unwieldy and as far as I understand you needed to change the code under test (which is not-a-good-thing-to-do (TM)).

Rather have a look into arquillian (http://arquillian.org/) and the use with mockito.

Here's a little bit of boilerplate code showing how I usually do this:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestParticipantListener {
    // Collection of producer methods and/or static producer fields
    // that mock the injected dependencies for the class under test
    public static class LocalMocks {
        @Produces ParticipantDAO getParticipantDAO() {
            ParticipantDAO participantDAO = Mockito.mock(...);
            return participantDAO
        }
    }

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        PomEquippedResolveStage pom = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml");
        BeansDescriptor beansXml = Descriptors.create(BeansDescriptor.class)
            .addDefaultNamespaces().getOrCreateAlternatives()
            .up();

        WebArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addAsLibraries(pom.resolve("org.mockito:mockito-core").withTransitivity().asFile())
            .addClass(ParticipantListener.class)
            .addClass(ParticipantDAO.class)
            .addClass(TestParticipantListener.LocalMocks.class)
            // ... other dependencies
            .addAsWebInfResource(new StringAsset(beansXml.exportAsString()), "beans.xml");

        return jar;
    }

    @Inject ParticipantListener participantListenerUnderTest;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ... whatever your test is, using the injected instance
    }
}
```